# Symfony Sonata admin find by some field

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-s3, sonata-admin, symfony-sonata

I install SonataAdminBundle and create controller extends Admin and function configureFormFields, configureDatagridFilters, configureListFields. And in field list I use field image but I see only url for image, my image live in amazon S3 I want see image in table. How I do this? And I have filter for find by colums, my entity developer have array skill and by one skill find good but how find for two or many skill ?

And I add for admin can do upload avatar for developer but in my action(not extends Admin) I upload like this for(field image in Developer = string and I set just url for S3)

```
        $url = sprintf(
        '%s%s',
        $this->container->getParameter('acme_storage.amazon_s3.base_url'),
        $this->getPhotoUploader()->upload($request->files->get('file'), $user_company_name)
    );

    $user->setImage($url);
```

how I can do for sonata, reload controller? How I do this ?

this my action:

```
class DeveloperAdmin extends Admin
{

protected function configureFormFields(FormMapper $formMapper)
{
    $formMapper

        ->add('firstName', null, array('label' => 'Developer\'s First Name', 'max_length' => 255))
        ->add('lastName', null, array('label' => 'Developer\'s Last Name', 'max_length' => 255))
        ->add('qualification', 'choice', array('label' => 'Speciality',
            'choices' => array('Frontend' => 'Frontend', 'Backend' => 'Backend', 'Full stack' => 'Full stack'),'attr'=> array('class'=>'qualif'), 'required' => false))
        ->add('level', 'choice', array('label' => 'Professional Level', 'max_length' => 255,
            'choices' => array('Junior' => 'Junior', 'Middle' => 'Middle', 'Senior' => 'Senior')))
        ->add('tags', 'tags', array('label' => 'Tags','required' => false))
        ->add('main_skill', 'mainSkill', array('label' => 'Main Skill', 'required' => true, 'mapped' => true, 'attr' => array('placeholder' => 'Select your skills ...', 'class'=>'main_skill') ))
        ->add('skills', 'skills', array('label' => 'Skills','required' => false))
        ->add('english', 'choice', array('label' => 'English Level', 'max_length' => 255,
            'choices' => array('Basic' => 'Basic', 'Intermediate' => 'Intermediate', 'Advanced' => 'Advanced')))
        ->add('rate', null, array('label' => 'Rate $/h', 'max_length' => 255));
         $image = $this->getSubject();

    $fileFieldOptions = array('required' => false);

    if ($image && ($webPath = $image->getImage())) {
        dump($image);exit; //I have all user and field image local url /temp/sdgsdg          
        $container = $this->getConfigurationPool()->getContainer();
        $fullPath = $container->get('request')->getBasePath().'/'.$webPath;
        $fileFieldOptions['help'] = '<img src="'.$fullPath.'" class="admin-preview" />';
    }

    $formMapper
        ->add('image', 'file', $fileFieldOptions)
}
protected function configureDatagridFilters(DatagridMapper $datagridMapper)
{
    $datagridMapper
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('main_skill')
        ->add('skills')
    ;
}
protected function configureListFields(ListMapper $listMapper)
{
    $listMapper
        ->addIdentifier('id')
        ->add('username')
        ->add('firstName')
        ->add('lastName')
        ->add('main_skill')
        ->add('skills')
        ->add('image', 'string', array('template' => 'SonataMediaBundle:MediaAdmin:list_image.html.twig'))

        ->add('_action', 'actions', array(
            'actions' => array(
                'show' => array(),
                'edit' => array(),
            )
        ))
    ;
}
```

}

How find by two or many skill ????
this is my entity:

```
class Developer extends CustomUser
{
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255,  unique=false, nullable=true)
 * @Assert\Length(min=3, max=255)
 */
protected $email;
////
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="skills", type="array")
 */
private $skills = array();
```

and in table for my developer in colum skill I see:

```
[0 => SOAP] [1 => Cisco] [2 => PHP] [3 => Sugar Crm] [4 => Hibernate] [5 => Java ME]
```

but when I add developer I use my service for skill and I see norm skill:

```
xPHP, xJava
```

How can fix this problem, reload template or controller ? Help please

Answer (score 1):

For this task use https://sonata-project.org/bundles/media/2-2/doc/index.html . It's very easy

Comment: If you about image then this is my problem
And I add for admin can do upload avatar for developer but in my action(not extends Admin) I upload like this for(field image in Developer = string and I set just url for S3)
            $url = sprintf(
            '%s%s',
            $this->container->getParameter('acme_storage.amazon_s3.base_url'),
            $this->getPhotoUploader()->upload($request->files->get('file'), $user_company_name)
        );

        $user->setImage($url);
how I can do for sonata, reload controller? How I do this ?